# How To Move A Python Module From Any SubDirectory To `Site Packages`?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, python-packaging

My Python module default PATH is:

```
/home/$username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

..and in another directory I have another python.exe :

```
mnt/d/Program Files (x86)/MGLTools-1.5.6/python.exe
```

...and in another directory I have modules I want to use:

```
mnt/d/Program Files (x86)/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/
```

..and if I want to run my program I have to use this command:

```
./mnt/d/Program Files (x86)/MGLTools-1.5.6/python.exe "mnt/d/Program Files (x86)/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor.py" -r a.pdb -o a.pdbqt
```

but I want to move all my modules under `/home/$username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages`
and I want to use only this command to run my program: `repare_receptor.py -r a.pdb -o a.pdbqt`

How can I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: You need to reinstall all the dependencies with the other Python interpreter. You can not mix dependencies between interpreters.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your answer. But if I do that, amber22 program crashes. I tried "alias" but it didn't work too.

Comment: You need to figure if it is possible (and how) on Windows to associate a specific Python script with a specific Python interpreter. Maybe look into the [_"Python launcher for Windows"_](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows).

Comment: We can not guess how and why things crash on you own computer. We can not guess what "amber22" is. If you provide a [mre] maybe someone will be able to help.